# Why we need to use annotations in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Is it necessary to use Annotations in Spring? Why and waht is besic purpose behind this use?

Comment: Read the manual. Seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not rule to use annotations,we can use xml configuration files to inject dependencies and to define beans,but if you don't know how to write xml it is burden on developer to define xml.so,for them annotations is convenient